# Python in Path but not working in powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, anaconda

I'm on client's machine. I've just installed Anaconda to `C:\Users\UserID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`.

I would like to run python on powershell. When I typed `python` into powershell, I'm getting the error `"The term 'python' is not recognized as that name of a cmdlet..."`

[image]

I `cd`'d into the anaconda directory where it's installed and type this `.\python.exe` and it launched a new  window below, but what I really want is to launch python from the powershell

[image]

I've been trying to figure out what I've done incorrectly here. The environment is quite restrictive as well such as editing system variables. However, I can edit User's Path

This is what I would like to happen (this is from my own dev PC):
[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. If you simply reinstall Python and choose to set the path while installing, it should work.

Comment: Why not add the path to `python.exe` to the User's `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Problem is i'm not even allowed to install python base interpreter. Even this anaconda I got was given to me. Too restrictive environment which I've flagged already. Also I did the install and uninstall.

Comment: Also it can’t find Python when it’s definitely installed and path are set correctly.  $PythonPath= gci C:\ -recurse -include python.exe -erroraction SilentlyContinue | select -Expand Directory -First 1 | select -Expand FullName

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. I checked the $env:PathExt. I found out it has only .CPL in it. Then I updated it by adding the following

```
;.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```